# How can I change the volume/gain of a tab (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create an extension that has the capabilities to change the volume of the current tab.
Specifically have the capabilities to go above 100% volume.

I have found a way to change the audio of videos with the video html tag, but this is not consistent depending on the website.

I can't find an chrome api or anything to help with this.

Does anyone have any insight about this topic?

This is the code I currently am using.

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector("video")     
var audioCtx = new AudioContext()     
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(videoElement)     
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain()     
gainNode.gain.value = 1     
source.connect(gainNode)     
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)
```